# numpy/scipy analog of matlab's fminsearch

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am converting some Matlab code into python using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). Everything worked pretty smoothly but recently I encountered [fminsearch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) function.

So, to cut it short: is there an easy way to make in python something like this:

```
banana = @(x)100*(x(2)-x(1)^2)^2+(1-x(1))^2;
[x,fval] = fminsearch(banana,[-1.2, 1])
```

which will return

```
x = 1.0000    1.0000
fval = 8.1777e-010
```

Up till now I have not found anything that looks similar in numpy. The only thing that I found similar is [scipy.optimize.fmin](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html). Based on the definition it

> Minimize a function using the downhill simplex algorithm.

But right now I can not find to write the above-mentioned Matlab code using this function

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's just a straight-forward conversion from Matlab syntax to python syntax:

```
import scipy.optimize

banana = lambda x: 100*(x[1]-x[0]**2)**2+(1-x[0])**2
xopt = scipy.optimize.fmin(func=banana, x0=[-1.2,1])
```

with output:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.000000
         Iterations: 85
         Function evaluations: 159
array([ 1.00002202,  1.00004222])
```

Answer (score 13):

`fminsearch` implements the Nelder-Mead method, see `Matlab` document: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html. In the reference section.

To find its equivalent in `scipy`, you just need to check the doc strings of the methods provided in `scipy.optimize`. See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy.optimize.fmin. `fmin` also implements Nelder-Mead method.

The names do not always translate directly from `matlab` to `scipy` and are sometimes even misleading. For example, Brent's method is implemented as `fminbnd` in `Matlab` but `optimize.brentq` in `scipy`. So, checking the doc strings are always a good idea.